# Unity PlayMode Tests - Lifecycle Events don't fire when running 21 or more tests together

Tags: unity, testing, unit-testing

I'm experiencing an issue with my PlayMode tests, where all tests pass individually, but when running 21 or more tests together (using Run Selected or Run All), the same 2 tests fail. From further investigation, it appears that the MonoBehaviour lifecycle events aren't firing when running all of the tests - when I run the tests individually, they fire as expected.

**Failing Tests**

[image: failing tests]

**Tests passing when run individually**

[image: tests passing]

These two tests are the only ones that depend on the `OnEnable()` lifecycle event being triggered. Here is the first test, `GivenCursorHasState_WhenEnabled_ThenTheCursorPositionShouldBeRestoredFromState()`

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator GivenCursorHasState_WhenEnabled_ThenTheCursorPositionShouldBeRestoredFromState()
{
    // Disable the component, expect OnDisable() to fire
    selection.enabled = false;
    yield return null;

    var state = new CursorState { cursorPosition = 5 };
    StateCache.Store(cursor, state);

    // Enable the component, expect OnEnable() to fire
    selection.enabled = true;
    yield return null;

    var expectedItem = menuItems[5];
    var actualItem = selection.GetCurrentItem();

    // The next line is where the failure is triggered
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedItem, actualItem);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedItem.transform.position.y, cursor.transform.position.y);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(expectedItem.transform.position.x, cursor.transform.position.x);
    Assert.AreEqual(originalCursorPositionX, cursor.transform.position.x);
}
```

This is the components, `OnEnable()` method:

```
void OnEnable()
{
    var state = StateCache.Get<CursorState>(gameObject);

    if (state == null)
    {
        SelectFirstEnabledItem();
    }
    else
    {
        // We might be retaining a position already in state
        cursorPosition = state.cursorPosition;

        UpdateCursorPosition();
    }
}
```

I'm setting up the test with the following method:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>("Assets/Prefabs/UI/Menu.prefab");
    var menu = GameObject.Instantiate<GameObject>(prefab);
    selection = menu.GetComponentInChildren<MenuItemSelection>();

    menuItems = selection.menuItems;
    cursor = selection.gameObject;
    originalCursorPositionX = cursor.transform.position.x;
}
```

I've checked the `StateCache` between steps, and that appears to be working as expected - as in there is no pollution between tests with it being a static class.

I'm hoping I'm just misunderstanding something about how the tests and/or lifecycle events work here. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Can you test whether it's really the sheer quantity of tests, and not something specific in the contents of the other tests? Try making a new project, and fill it up with 20+ tests that all just immediately succeed, plus one of the tests that's currently misbehaving. If it fails there too, that sounds like a Unity bug. If it works there, then it sounds like an interaction between the contents of some of your tests.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm having trouble setting up an isolated reproduction of this issue, so I either don't understand it enough, or I'm missing something specific to my project. This is the repro project I have started adding to: https://github.com/sladesamuel/unity-lifecycle-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I reworked this solution. Instead of using a static `StateCache` instance with static data that was clearly bleeding through my tests when run in batch, I made use of dependency injection. The framework I used for this was [Zenject](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject).

In my game code, I now setup my `StateCache` as a singleton dependency, but within the context of my tests, I change this to a transient instance. This allows my tests to be completely isolated, and therefore no state bleeding occurs between tests.